# Did they manage to extract any information from Annie Leonhart after she was captured?

Tags: attack-on-titan

She was grounded and held underground deep inside the walls, but what about it?
Did they manage to extract any information from her? If no then why? Getting by without saying a word is too good for her!

Comment: This appears to be asking several different questions. If I'm not mistaken and that's the case, it's best to break them down into separate posts.

Comment: I guess what you are saying is right. This question should ask only about Annie questions. Imma do the braking right away!@Maroon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as the story goes, they were not able to abstract any information from [Annie](http://shingekinokyojin.wikia.com/wiki/Annie_Leonhart) yet, because she had covered her whole body in a particularly hard crystal.

This happened back in chapter 34, but was the last we have heard and seen from Annie.

[image: enter image description here!]